# Lookup data while in mysql cli edit mode (external editor) (\e)

Tags: mysql, client, native-client

I'm using the mysql cli in edit mode (\e).

```
> Select * from \e
```

Goes to vim and I finish typing my command.

```
Select * from test_table;
```

Only to realize I've forgotten to `use` the database I need.  Is there a way I can preserve this script in edit mode, switch back to the regular mysql mode, run my command, and then come back to edit?

Another example would be: I forget how a column name is spelled and I need to look it up after I've started typing a command in edit mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, sort of.

In vim, save your work to a different file...

```
:w myfile.sql [enter]
```

Then exit vim with an artificial error so the `mysql` client won't bother to re-read the temporary file.

```
:cq [enter]
```

Then clear the input buffer in `mysql`.

```
\c [enter]
```

Then do what you've gotta do.

Then re-launch vim

```
\e [enter]
```

The editor will have your last command in it.  Clear that out and then paste the temporary file back into the buffer.

```
:r myfile.sql [enter]
```

Keep editing, then save and exit and your new content will be returned to mysql for execution.

Comment: It sounds like there is no other way... although I thought I remembered an old colleague doing something without having to use your method.  If no one else offers an answer in a couple days, I'll mark yours as the correct answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Sounds good.  I checked the source of `client/mysql.cc` and didn't see anything but if someone else has ideas for alternate approaches, I'll be interested to see them, too.